# I would make jBoss 5.1 to show the admin console

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss

i just downloaded a fresh new JBoss 5.1 GA, unpackaged and linked to my Eclipse Juno.

When i start Jboss from the JAVAEE perspective and i access path "localhost:8080" it opens the main webpage of the JBoss, but Administration console is lost.

I have java jre 7 installed on my pc, and with jboss 7.1 i had never had similar problems...

If i'm missing some vital info, please tell me, i'll provide.

thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try one of the below URLs

```
http://localhost:8080/jmx-console/
```

or

```
http://localhost:8080/web-console/
```

Edit: There is no console for administration, but you can deploy [RHQ](http://www.jboss.org/rhq/) (Jopr) that does the same task.

Comment: hi , thanks 4 your reply, this 2 links are available. but they're not the administration console...

Comment: There is not admin console in the newer versions of jboss. You have to install another separate application that acts as an admin console. Try : http://www.jboss.org/rhq/

Comment: But there is an admin-console in JBoss 5.1 which the OP has referenced.

Answer (score 3):

There is an admin-console.war included in your JBoss download.
If it's not in the server profile that you start, you can copy it from another.

See this -
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/JBoss_Enterprise_Application_Platform_Common_Criteria_Certification/5/html-single/Administration_Console_Quick_Start_Guide/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Try with this URL -

```
http://localhost:9990/console
```

or

```
http://localhost:9999/console
```

if, you are unable to login still. check for admin ports in standalone.xml file in jboss server.

Thanks.